# PowerShell: finding which groups are attached to which folders

Tags: powershell, file-permissions

(This is my first post, so sorry if I'm hard to understand or asked a bad question)

### Here is my problem:

I have a few AD Groups with a similar naming convention. "*somename" and I used Get-ADGroup command to get an array filled with those objects.

Similarly, I have folders with NTFS permissions on them which I have in another array. These permissions are a mix of the groups I mentioned earlier, as well as other groups and individual users as needed.

### End Goal (What I would like to find):

- Which folders do not have any of those AD Groups assigned.
- And which of those AD Groups aren't attached to any folders.
- Which folders have which AD Group from that list assigned to it.

### Here is what I have tried

```
$CS_Dirs=get-childitem '\\my.server\share$\Dept' -recurse -depth 1 -filter copierscans
$CS_Roles=Get-ADGroup -filter {Name -like "* CopierScans"}

####For each directory in $CS_Dirs array, get acl###
foreach($dir in $CS_Dirs){

    ###Get the ACL for the Dir###
    get-acl $dir.PSPath | %{

        ####Variable to tell this loop if next loops find a match###
        $contains=$false

        ####For every access object in that ACL###
        foreach ($access in $_.access){

            ###loop through each group to check if any of the dir's ACL's principals are in my list of AD Groups.
            foreach($group in $CS_ADGrups){

                #If they are then set contains to true to tell the outer loop to select that path
                if($access.identityreference.ToString() -match {"DOMAIN\"+$group.name.ToString()}){
                    $contains=$true
                }
            }
        }

        #Should be a list of all the paths
        #Which are not assigned a group contained in my $CS_ADGroups list.
        if($contains){
            $_ | select @{n="path";e={$_.path}}
        }
    }
}
```

### The Issues:

The matching in the end of the foreach I can't get to match eachother

- The matching in the end of the foreach, i can't get it to evaluate true properly when they match. partly because one of them has the domain attached to the front and the other doesn't (hence the "domain\" portion)
- I can't get it to select the directory path when it's inside a foreach loop,

Answer (score 4):

It is difficult to see the errors you're getting without a similar environment to run it against. I can make the following two suggestions.

1) Get-Childitem does not return any items with a "path" property. Try using the "Fullname" property instead.

2) When you attempt to match a string that contains characters that perform special regex functions (like \$^?.) you need to escape those so they can be matched. Backslash is the primary escape character in regular expressions.

```
$group = "DOMAIN\Some Group"
$group -match $group
False
$group -match [regex]::Escape($group)
True

[Regex]::Escape("DOMAIN\Some Group")
DOMAIN\\Some\ Group
help about_regular_expressions
```

Try the following on the right side of your `-match`

```
-match ( [regex]::Escape("Domain\" + $group.name))
```

Comment: I got it working. I guess -match isn't what I needed. So I ended up using -like with just a wildcard appended to the name like "*" + $group.name which ended up working. Also, the Get-ChildItem wasn't what I was trying to get the path off of. I was getting the .path property off of the Get-ACL objects. Which do have a path. Finally I got through my problem with the select inside of the foreach loop by creating an $externalVariable = @() and appending to it every time I selected. Not my ideas situation, but it worked. Thanks.